# Contar el numero de coincidencias de un valor en un array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Intento que el programa me devuelva el número de ocurrencias de un valor en un array pero no entiendo por qué el output me da distinto a lo que debería, este el código que tengo:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr11=(0,1,2,4)
sum=0
for ((i=0;i<4;i=i+1)); do
    if [[ ${arr11[$i]} -eq 0 ]]; then
            ((sum++))
    fi
done
echo $sum
```

El output me sale 3 no se por qué.

Answer (score 3):

#### Respuesta corta

En lugar de:

```
declare -a arr11=(0,1,2,4)
```

Utiliza espacios para separar los valores:

```
declare -a arr11=(0 1 2 4)
```

Por otro lado, otra opción que no implica únicamente Bash es usar `grep`:

```
declare -a arr11=(0 1 2 4 0 3 0 2)
valor_a_buscar=0

grep -c "$valor_a_buscar" <( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${arr11[*]}" )
```

Aquí desempaquetamos los valores del array `arr11` separados por el caracter de salto de línea `\n` (es decir, en renglones separados), y luego `grep` cuenta las coincidencias del valor a buscar.

#### Respuesta larga

En Bash, los valores dentro de un array no se dan separados por comas, sino por valores de la variable `IFS`; es decir, un espacio  , un caracter `\t`, o un salto de línea `\n`.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ declare -a arr1=( valor1 valor2 )
$ declare -a arr2=(
    valor1
    valor2
)
```

Si el output te sale "3", es porque tu array (¡De sólo un valor, puesto que no indicaste varios separándolos con espacios!), fue recorrido 4 veces. La primera vez, su valor fue de la cadena "0,1,2,3", entonces la condición `[[ valor -eq 0 ]]` da falso, entonces no se aumenta la variable `sum`.

Las siguientres **tres veces**, su valor fue igual a cero, puesto que cualquier número después del primer y **único** valor será cero a no haber nada más. Por lo tanto la variable `sum` será aumentada en uno tres veces.

Por otro lado, para mejorar tu código puedes dejar de utilizar constantes. Mejor utilizar variables y procedimientos sobre estos para hacerlo un tanto más flexible.

Por ejemplo, en el caso de al iterar sobre los valores, puedes utilizar el mecanismo llamado *parameter expansion* donde el token `@` dentro de los corchetes, sustituye todos los valores dentro del array separados por un espacio. En otras palabras, iteramos sobre todos los valores (¡Más no las claves!).

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr11=(0 1 2 4 0 3 0 2)
valor_a_buscar=0

for numero in ${arr11[@]}; do
    [[ "$numero" -eq "$valor_a_buscar" ]] && ((sum++))
done

echo $sum
```

Entonces, corres el programa y obtienes esto:

```
$ ./programa
3
```

Puesto que en el array, el valor 0 se encuentra 3 veces.

Answer (score 0):

En la condición del for debes indicar `i<=4` en lugar de `i<4` ya que el que tienes puesto una vez que la i llega a 4 no entra en el for.
Otra solución posible es a la salida del for poner un `sum++`.

Yo lo dejaría así:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr11=(0,1,2,4)
sum=0
for ((i=0;i<=4;i=i+1)); do
    if [[ ${arr11[$i]} -eq 0 ]]; then
            ((sum++))
    fi
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: Tu explicación no da al problema, además, al correr tu código, no se muestran las veces que el cero se encuentra en el array.

Comment: Sigue estando mal el output :(